Can a phone's metadata date be wrong?
I had a flood a month ago,placed a claim with the contents insurance for a few items. They sent an assessor.
In passing conversation I mentioned that we had a flood a few years ago(this flood was massive and devastated our city) and that the boundary walls etc got damaged but the neighbors' insurance sorted that out.
This flood happened long before I had this contents insurance and had nothing to do with the contents of the house. It was buildings insurance that was on the name of the owner of the house.
I am with this contents insurance for 2 years now and had 1 claim with them 6 months ago which was for flood damage of small items. That claim was approved and paid out.
(Yes I know 2 claims with flood damage but I live in a low laying area in a subtropical climate. We are prone to floods and the floods that I claimed for were documented on the news.
Anyway back to the new claim. The assessor took the damaged items and sent the report to the insurance. Yesterday the insurance called me and said they looked through the previous claim that they paid out 6 months ago and noticed that a picture from there had a metadata date for 2022. I said I don't know how that was possible as there is another picture of the same item with the correct metadata date.
She continued to shout at me like I was a criminal because I didn't have an answer for her. She said even though nothing was wrong with the new claim because of the picture from the old claim, My old claim is rejected and the legal department will call me about the funds they paid out and they will be taking action on my policy.
I don't know what to do. She insinuated that I committed fraud and I'm so stressed out that it's making me physically sick.
I did not send them an old picture. When the flood happened 6 months ago we lost power for over 24 hours. No electricity, no internet nothing. I took pictures of the damage with my phone then the battery died so my husband took pictures on his phone and an old blackberry that we had. We uploaded all the pictures onto the laptop and when power was restored sent it to the insurance.
The picture in question comes from the old blackberry which is broken. It had no sim in it and the software is corrupt so it's basically a glorified camera that I have to plug into the laptop to take pictures from.
I checked online and they say metadata can be wrong if the phone time and date settings are wrong or if there is connectivity issues at the time of taking the picture. I think that is what happened.
Is it possible and what do I do?
If they tell me to pay that money back I can't afford to. I live in a house of 7, my husband is the only one that works. I look after my grandmother who is blind.
What if they want to press charges, I can't prove that I didn't do it.
It is their word against mine.

It is their word against mine. Don't you still have a copy of the picture yourself? Any decent image viewer will show you EXIF data. It's quite conceivable that a derelict phone has the wrong date in it: with no SIM its date won't be synchronised.

This is really lawyer territory.  Especially if the insurance company is coming at you over a single photo.

Get a lawyer. Get a notary to witness you taking a photo with the Blackberry and documenting that the date in the EXIF Info from that photo is not correct.

@MichaelC Wouldn't that simply be the notary signing an affidavit testifying that they the witnessed the action of taking a photo and reviewing the resulting EXIF data?  In which case I am unsure if they can notarize their own signature.

Yes of course it can and there are numerous ways that it can occur including:

Time/Date manually or never set and Auto-update is off
Time/Date was set then power lost and well as connectivity no/poor signal/Wi-Fi
Incorrect date/time received from server either due to error or malicious activity.
Data loss/corruption on SD card or other storage device.
Elderly devices storing date/time in non-standard formats.

Another possibility is that the image contains visible time/date stamp in US format (mm/dd/yyyy) and the viewer is from a more sane country so reads 01/08/2022 as the first of August rather than January 8th. Of course if the viewer is from a very few places that use ISO format day to day they would read 01-08-22 as 22nd August 2001. Of course the phones date format could be set to a dd/mm/yy or yy-mm-dd format and the viewer be reading it as if it were something else.
As general advice I would say, especially if you are likely to have to make future claims, that any sequence of shots intended for use supporting an insurance claim start with a photograph of something that nails the date down, such as the newspaper, a bill or better yet a letter from the insurance company that will prove that the photographs could not have been taken any earlier than the date on the paper/document.

Steve, I like your recommendation of including in the frame a letter from the insurance company.  I would love to see an insurance company claim that the letter must have been written be one of their own representatives who was a time traveler and therefore the letter was not valid proof.  Of course, many of us have seen insurance companies make arguments that are nearly as preposterous...

There are two issues, one technical-photographic and the other legal. The legal issues are not addressed in this answer.
Not only is it possible for a phone to record the incorrect date, it can record incorrect data in any EXIF category. This was addressed by @Steve Barnes.
The other technical issue is that editing or deleting an image file's metadata is trivially easy to do. Most image editing software can delete or edit the data. Dedicated software like exiftool allow editing of all classes of an image's metadata. The source of edits done in this manner is not detectable. Even if the date or location of the image is changed to the year 2148 and a location of "On the moon," there is no way to tell from the file what the origin of that data is.

If the image ever got filtered or resized it could have been written to a new file.  This file could have a new creation time.
This is probably the simplest way to accidentally change a date on an image.
A date in the EXIF shooting information that changed probably requires more intent, unless the program author for a filter was a little stupid.
